# xamarin Android Developing basic concept

Tags: c#, android

I need some basic help about xamarin basic's.
can anyone guide me about  Xamarin basic concept like selecting layout ,like resize button etc..

Comment: Yes, the best guide, go to the Xamarin examples, download them, read the documentation and play with them until you understand how to use Xamarin Android.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest doing an intro tutorial from a well known blog or even Youtube to get the gist of how to develop an Xamarin application. There you should be able to pick up the basic concepts. Tutsplus has an excellent 3 part tutorial which I found very helpful [link](http://code.tutsplus.com/series/an-introduction-to-xamarin--cms-642)